# Push array with check condition in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

#### dashboardCtrl

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {  
    //Color
    $scope.Color = [{
        colorname: "Red",
        number: "(3)"
    }, {
        colorname: "Brown",
        number: "(9)"
    }, {
        colorname: "yellow",
        number: "(5)"
    }, {
        colorname: "Violet",
        number: "(6)"
    }, {
        colorname: "Orange",
        number: "(1)"
    }, {
        colorname: "Blue",
        number: "(4)"
    }]
    //price
    $scope.Price = [{
        pricename: "Below $ 100",

    }, {
        pricename: "$ 100-500",
    }, {
        pricename: "$ 1k-10k",
    }, {
        pricename: "$ 10k-20k",
    }, {
        pricename: "$ Above 20k",
    }]

    //Product1
    $scope.Products1 = [{
            url: "images/3.jpg",
            id: 18,
            category: "Samsung Galaxy (3)",
            Name: "Samsung Galaxy (3)",
            Price: "300",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false

        },
        {
            url: "images/4.jpg",
            id: 21,
            category: "Samsung Galaxy (5)",
            Name: "Samsung Galaxy (5)",
            Price: "400",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false


        },
        {
            url: "images/5.jpg",
            id: 23,
            category: "Samsung Galaxy (4)",
            Name: "Samsung Galaxy (4)",
            Price: "350",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false

        },
        {
            url: "images/6.jpg",
            id: 24,
            category: "Nexus",
            Name: "Nexus",
            Price: "120",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false

        }
    ];

    //Product 3
    $scope.Products3 = [{
            url: "images/8.jpg",
            id: 19,
            category: "G Speaker",
            Name: "G Speaker",
            Price: "28",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false
        },
        {
            url: "images/18.jpg",
            id: 82,
            category: "Hp PURE",
            Name: "Hp PURE",
            Price: "100",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false

        },
        {
            url: "images/7.jpg",
            id: 37,
            category: "G5 Mobile",
            Name: "G5 Mobile",
            Price: "60",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false
        },
        {
            url: "images/6.jpg",
            id: 54,
            category: "Nexus",
            Name: "Nexus",
            Price: "220",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false

        }
    ];
    //product2
    $scope.Products2 = [{
            url: "images/11.jpg",
            id: 10,
            category: "Hp Pavilion g6",
            Name: "Hp Pavilion g6",
            Price: "700",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false


        },
        {
            url: "images/12.jpg",
            id: 20,
            category: "Hp Ivy Brigh",
            Name: "Hp Ivy Brigh",
            Price: "900",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false


        },
        {
            url: "images/9.jpg",
            id: 30,
            category: "Samsung Headphone",
            Name: "Samsung Headphone",
            Price: "100",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false

        },
        {
            url: "images/10.jpg",
            id: 40,
            category: "MP3 Player",
            Name: "MP3 Player",
            Price: "90",
            qty: 1,
            showAddToCart: false,
            addedToCart: false
        },
    ];

    //MyCart
    $scope.myCartItems = [];

    $scope.addToCart = function (item) {
        item.qty++;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addProduct', item.Price);
        $scope.myCartItems.push(item);
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (index) {
        $scope.myCartItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
}]);
```

> html

```
<body>

    <!-- banner -->
    <div class="banner banner1">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Great Offers on
                <span>Mobiles</span> Flat
                <i>35% Discount</i>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- breadcrumbs -->
    <div class="breadcrumb_dress">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //breadcrumbs -->
    <!-- mobiles -->
    <div class="mobiles">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grids">
                <div class="col-md-4 w3ls_mobiles_grid_left">
                    <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_left_grid">
                        <h3>Categories</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_left_grid">
                        <h3>Color</h3>
                        <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_left_grid_sub">
                            <div class="ecommerce_color" ng-repeat="x in Color ">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:void[0]">
                                            <i></i> {{x.colorname+x. number}}</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_left_grid">
                        <h3>Price</h3>
                        <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_left_grid_sub">
                            <div class="ecommerce_color ecommerce_size" ng-repeat="y in Price ">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>{{y.pricename}}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 w3ls_mobiles_grid_right">

                    <!--    <div id='z'>{{ze}}</div> -->

                    <div class="col-md-6 w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_left">
                        <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_grid1">
                            <img src="images/46.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_grid1_pos1">
                                <h3>Smart Phones
                                    <span>Up To</span> 15% Discount</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_left">
                        <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_grid1">
                            <img src="images/47.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_grid1_pos">
                                <h3>Top 10 Latest
                                    <span>Mobile </span>& Accessories</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_grid2">
                        <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_grid2_left">
                            <h3>Showing Results: 0-1</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3ls_mobiles_grid_right_grid2_right">
                            <p>Filtering Inputs </p>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search">

                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in Products1  | filter:search | orderBy:'category' track by $index">
                            <img ng-src="{{item.url}}">
                            <br> {{item.category}}
                            <br>
                            <label>Price</label>
                            {{item.Price | currency}}
                            <br>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="item.qty" min="1" class="qty">
                            <br>
                            <label>Total</label> {{ item.qty * item.Price | currency }}
                            <br>
                            <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                <button type="submit" class="w3ls-cart" ng-click="addToCart(item)" value="Save Data">Add to cart</button>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in Products2  | filter:search | orderBy:'category'">
                            <img ng-src="{{item.url}}">
                            <br> {{item.category}}
                            <br>
                            <label>Price</label>
                            {{item.Price | currency}}
                            <br>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="item.qty" min="1" class="qty">
                            <br>
                            <label>Total</label> {{ item.qty * item.Price | currency }}
                            <br>
                            <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                <button type="submit" class="w3ls-cart" ng-click="addToCart(item)" value="Save Data">Add to cart</button>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in Products3  | filter:search | orderBy:'id'">
                            <img ng-src="{{item.url}}">
                            <br> {{item.category}}
                            <br>
                            <label>Price</label>
                            {{item.Price | currency}}
                            <br>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="item.qty" min="1" class="qty">
                            <br>
                            <label>Total</label> {{ item.qty * item.Price | currency }}
                            <br>
                            <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                <button type="submit" class="w3ls-cart" ng-click="addToCart(item)" value="Save Data">Add to cart</button>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>

                <div class="footer-copy">
                    <div class="footer-copy1">
                        <div class="footer-copy-pos">
                            <a href="javascript:void[0]" class="scroll">
                                <img src="images/arrow.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <h2>Cart</h2>
                    <div ng-repeat="product in myCartItems">
                        {{product.qty + ' x ' +product.category+'= Total '}}{{product.Price*product.qty | currency}}
                        <a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <p>&copy; 2018 Store. All rights reserved
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- //footer -->
</body>
```

Comment: I am building a cart but i want to put a if condition to  addToCart(item)

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to set the value of item.qty in $scope.myCartItems to avoid dupes error in angularjs

Comment: I want to set the value of item.qty in $scope.myCartItems to avoid dupes error in angularjs

Answer (score 1):

If you want an if condition, what's stopping you from adding one?

```
$scope.addToCart = function (item) {
    if( /* some conditions are met */ ) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
    item.qty++;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addProduct', item.Price);
    $scope.myCartItems.push(item);
}
```